# Transpose from vertical to horizontal with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move the following data from it's vertical state to horizontal data. I would like a solution in VBA.

```
| abc.com  | result 1
| abc.com  | result 2
| abc.com  | result 3
| xyz.com  | result 1
| xyz.com  | result 2
| xyz.com  | result 3
```

I want it to resolve as

```
| abc.com  | result 1 | result 2 | result 3
| xyz.com  | result 1 | result 2 | result 3 | result 4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you've written so far as an attempt, this isn't a code for me site.

Comment: try Googling how to use a `Dictionary` in Excel VBA

Comment: If you have some knoledge of VBA you coul try this:
Create a functions that elimates duplicates in the first column then store unique values into a matrix and finally use `application.vlookup` to display the results. If you need more feedback please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy!  Just do a Text To Columns, to get your data setup correctly.  Maybe it is correct on your side; it looks kind of weird in the same ple that you posed.  Anyway, in A1:B6 I have this.

```
 abc.com     result 1
 abc.com     result 2
 abc.com     result 3
 xyz.com     result 1
 xyz.com     result 2
 xyz.com     result 3
```

Then, simply run the script below.

```
Sub ConcatData()
Dim X As Double
Dim DataArray(5000, 2) As Variant
Dim NbrFound As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Found As Integer
Dim NewWks As Worksheet

Cells(1, 1).Select
Let X = ActiveCell.Row
Do While True
If Len(Cells(X, 1).Value) = Empty Then
Exit Do
End If
If NbrFound = 0 Then
NbrFound = 1
DataArray(1, 1) = Cells(X, 1)
DataArray(1, 2) = Cells(X, 2)
Else
For Y = 1 To NbrFound
Found = 0
If DataArray(Y, 1) = Cells(X, 1).Value Then
DataArray(Y, 2) = DataArray(Y, 2) & ", " & Cells(X, 2)
Found = 1
Exit For
End If
Next
If Found = 0 Then
NbrFound = NbrFound + 1
DataArray(NbrFound, 1) = Cells(X, 1).Value
DataArray(NbrFound, 2) = Cells(X, 2).Value
End If
End If
X = X + 1
Loop

Set NewWks = Worksheets.Add
NewWks.Name = "SummarizedData"
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Names"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Results"
X = 2
For Y = 1 To NbrFound
Cells(X, 1).Value = DataArray(Y, 1)
Cells(X, 2).Value = DataArray(Y, 2)
X = X + 1
Next
Beep
MsgBox ("Summary is done!")
End Sub
```

Just make sure you have a sheet named "SummarizedData"!